# CSS: Select the first div with tag itemprop

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div itemprop="description"></div>
</div>
<div itemprop="description"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

How to select only the first div with itemprops=description?
Or how to select the 3rd div inside #wrapper div?

Comment: `#wrapper div:last-child{...}`

Comment: *How to select only the first div with itemprops=description?* -- You can't. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/1355315

Comment: With CSS you can't; with JavaScript you have the option of: `document.querySelector('div[itemprop=description]');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific case:

```
#wrapper > div:nth-child(3)
```

Though if the markup is likely to change, a better option would be to use a class or id, if possible.

Comment: yes, the first option doesn't work, the second does the job!

Comment: it won't if the structure changes and the first `itemprop` goes from `n = 3` to `n = {{anything_else}}`

Comment: Right, I was too eager to answer and didn't realy think about it, sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

If you can, add a class to the element you wish to target, e.g.:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="{{target-class}}" itemprop="description"></div>
    <div itemprop="description"></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Then use your "target" class name to select the relevant element. Its much cleaner and will cover you in the case of changes to the DOM.

I wouldn't advice targeting an element using `nth-child` unless you are targeting an element exclusively because it is the nth element.

An alternative would be to target the element by targeting all elements after it, e.g.

```
[itemprop="description"] {
    /* targeted */
}
[itemprop="description"] ~ [itemprop="description"] {
    /* not targeted */
}
```

You can see an example of that working [here](http://codepen.io/alexander-holman/pen/KgBqLK)

Answer (score 0):

Here are your options with CSS alone using some advanced selectors.

#### option 1

As there is currently only 1 itemprop div within the #wrapper, just select the div using the itemprop attribute - [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jessengatai/kw3szm6u/)

```
#wrapper div[itemprop="description"] { // your style }
```

#### option 2

This will select the last child element provided it's a div

```
#wrapper div:last-of-type { // your style }
```

#### option 3

As others have pointed out you can use :nth-child() selector. I wouldn't recommend this if the number of divs within #wrapper will vary though.

```
#wrapper div:nth-child(3) {
  // your style
}
```

#### option 4

If you're going to have multiple itemprop divs inside the wrapper you can cancel out styling by selecting siblings. However, this will only work on the itemprop divs within the #wrapper.

```
#wrapper div[itemprop="description"] { // your style }
#wrapper div[itemprop="description"] ~ div[itemprop="description"] { // cancel out styling }
```

Comment: Option 4 is actually a really good idea. I wouldn't have thought of that.